# Is there a way to specify the ordering of traces in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I am dynamically generating data based on multiple user input values, and then graphing the resulting traces on a single graph. Because there are many traces, I set the alpha of the `fillcolor` to 1, so the colors stay crisp. I am also stacking the traces, and would like to have the trace value at the end (with the largest value) in the back of the graph, and the smallest value (the first trace) in the front. However, it seems that plotly adds each successive trace to the front. Is there any way to tell plotly to add a trace to the back, e.g.

```
plot <- plotly_empty()
color.first <- ## Some color with alpha of 1
color.second <- ## Some color with alpha of 1
x.data.first <- 1:10
y.data.first <- 1:10
plot <- plot %>% add_trace(x = x.data.first, y = y.data.first, fill = 'tozeroy', color = color.first, fillcolor = color.first)
x.data.second <- 1:10
y.data.second <- (1:10) + y.data.first
plot <- plot %>% add_trace(x = x.data.second, y = y.data.second, fill = 'tozeroy', color = color.second, fillcolor = color.second)
plot
```

Will create a plot where the second set of data (`x.data.second`, `y.data.second`) is visible, but because the fillcolor's alpha level is 1, the first set of data is not visible. I am looking for an option like

```
add_trace(..., toback = TRUE)
```

Where `toback` would specify that the trace being added should be added behind the existing traces.

It would be possible for me to calculate all the data and the total in one section, and then graph the resulting list of traces backwards in a different section. That feels inefficient, when I have all the data I need in one place.

Comment: Honest question: is it too difficult to reverse the order of your data?

Comment: The actual data I am graphing is calculated from a large data table. I am usually graphing 6 traces and the sum of them, but it should respond to user input, so graphing 5 traces and their sum is also possible. I am calculating the sum as I add traces to the graph.